# Reading text values from selected fields in php

Tags: php

When I try to read the dropdown with `$data['fieldname']` , I expect to get back the text that’s displayed in the field, but that isn’t what happens. Dropdowns always point to either another record instance or an element of a list; these instances and elements all have an internal ID, and that internal ID is what I get back.
But what if I actually want the text that’s displayed in the dropdown?

Comment: When you submit a form, only the `value` attributes of the selected options are sent to the server, not the text. You can use an associative array to get the corresponding text.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I'm a newbie. An example should be explicative for me. I use phprunner to generate code

Comment: I'm not familiar with phprunner. But I imagine it should provide built-in ways to relate the values when it's creating the form and processing the response.

Answer (score 0):

When submitting a form, what you get is just `the value of the selected option`, and not the text. However, there is a way to bypass it if you really need the text. The strategy is to add a `hidden` input to your form, and fill it with the text of the selected option whenever a new option is selected. It will be something like the following code:

```
<form action="somewhere.php" method="POST">
    <select name="field" id="field" onchange="document.getElementById('content1').value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].text]">
    <option value="1">First Value</option>
    <option value="2">Second Value</option>
    </select>

    <input type="hidden" name="fieldname" id="content1" value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Explanation: here we have a dropdown named `field`, and there is an `onchange` event for this dropdown. Whenever a new option is selected, we put the text of that option into the `hidden` input which is called `content1`. The name of this hidden input is `fieldname`, so when this form is submitted, you can get the text in the post variable: `$_POST['fieldname'];`